# youtube api player not working on iOS?

Tags: ios, apache-flex, api, youtube

I'm using the YouTube API in my flex app to play videos and it works fine running on my computer and android, but I'm getting an issue when I try to use it on iOS, I just get a black screen!

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this violate iOS Guidelines about loading external SWFs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious so did some research.

First, I searched for SWFLoader on iOS and this [post came up](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891723).  I'll quote:

> You cannot load SWFS that run ActionScript on IOS

Then I realized from your comment you may be using the Loader class; so I googled Flash Loader on iOS and came across [this](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?355200-Dynamic-image-loading-for-Flash-Applications-for-iOS).  To quote:

> In an iPhone application, you cannot use the Loader.load() method.
>   However, you cannot run any ActionScript code in SWF content loaded
>   with the Loader.load() method. However, you can use assets in the SWF
>   file (such as movie clips, images, fonts, and sounds in the library).
>   You can also use the Loader.load() method to load image files.

You may benefit from reading through the actual [Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/index.html).  Specifically this [page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/WS789ea67d3e73a8b24b55b57a124b32b5b57-7fff.html) which focuses on unsupported APIs.  It is the last link where the above quote comes from.

Comment: thank you- i'll have to launch the player and not have everything contained in my app :(

Comment: @Lagoo87: what do you mean by "launch the player and not have everything contained in my app" because even I am stuck with same problem. Can you please provide your solution so it can help other travelers too?

Comment: @Reboog711: what can be an alternative to playing youtube videos on IOS? Can you please also look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297488/how-to-play-youtube-videos-on-ios-using-actionscript-3). Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's true you cannot load and run a SWF and in this case the video is a stream so you there is no media to save. Youtube does have an alternative URL that points to an actual mp4 file which will play on iOS. You can use a VideoDisplay player and that URL to play the video.

Comment: Can you take a look at a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297488/how-to-play-youtube-videos-on-ios-using-actionscript-3)? thanks