# How to play youtube videos on IOS using Actionscript 3

Tags: ios, actionscript, air, flex4, youtube-api

I am trying to fetch youtube playlist and play videos on IOS. My app works fine on Android and Flex simulators but does not work on IOS. Looks like there is a limitation on loading swfs in IOS [here](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/891723).

I am using [as3-youtube-data-api](https://code.google.com/p/as3-youtube-data-api/) for the purpose. Can anyone guide me on how can I embed or play youtube videos using as3 (Flash Builder 4.5) on IOS or is there any other way available?

Note: There is "Cisco Technical Support" app in app store, which plays youtube videos embedded in the app.

**Update**
can [VideoDisplay](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d7f.html) work, as I do not have mp4 for my playlists?

**More Update**

this is how at least m able to play youtube videos on IOS ([read this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started)), but again android gives me a black screen. Is there something I can do with this approach? Please give your suggestions. Thanks

```
var webView:StageWebView;
public function init():void
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;

    webView = new StageWebView(); 
    webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 35, this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight); 
    webView.stage = this.stage; 
    var htmlString:String = "<!DOCTYPE HTML>" + 
        "<html><body><script>" +
        "var tag = document.createElement('script');"+ 
        "tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\";"+ 
        "var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];"+ 
        "firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);"+
        "var player;"+

        "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {"+
            "player = new YT.Player('player', {"+             
              "events: {"+
                "'onReady': onPlayerReady,"+
                "'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange"+
              "}"+
            "});"+
        "}"+
        "function onPlayerReady(event) {"+
            "event.target.playVideo();"+
        "}"+
        "var done = false;"+
          "function onPlayerStateChange(event) {"+
            "if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {"+
              "setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);"+
              "done = true;"+
            "}"+
          "}"+
          "function stopVideo() {"+
            "player.stopVideo();"+
        "}"+

        "</script>"+
        "<iframe id=\"player\" type=\"text/html\" width=\"100%\" height=\"400\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/g-YW2jkd-Ac\" frameborder=\"0\"></iframe>" + 
        "</body></html>"; 
    webView.loadString( htmlString );
    //webView.loadURL("http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE");
}
public function dispose():void {
    try {
        webView.stage=null;
    } catch (e:Error) { trace("error")} 
}
```

Using `Capabilities.os` I can identify the OS and work my way through IOS and android.

Again, we [cannot invoke javascript in IOS](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/07/flex-mobile-invoking-javascript-in-a-stagewebview/), so I am unable to stop the video.

**Update**

This is what I did for IOS. It gives in built player controls

```
public function initIOS():void
{
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;

webView = new StageWebView();

webView.viewPort = new Rectangle( 0, 40, this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight-40);

webView.stage = this.stage; 
webView.loadURL("http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+data.videoId+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noted with the link you provided, you can't run actionscript swfs on iOS. It won't be long before there won't be any way to do it on Android, either. VideoDisplay also won't work because, well, it's actionscript.

To play Youtube videos on iOS, you can use (as the app you mentioned and other youtube-based apps on iOS do) the [native Objective-C libraries](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/), which will have full support for fetching playlists and playing videos; or could also try using the javascript client in a webapp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started) which lets me play videos on IOS, but not sure how I can stop the video and other stuff, is this iframe method correct? Any suggestions on this? I have updated my question with iframe usage which is able to play youtube videos on IOS.

Comment: I am using [as3-youtube-data-api](https://code.google.com/p/as3-youtube-data-api/) which in turn uses the [native Objective-C Library for youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Any help?

Comment: No, the as3-youtube-data-api doesn't use Objective-C ... it uses Actionscript, which can't run on iOS. If the necessary javascript to control the player isn't working for you, you'll need to write a native iOS app, with XCode and Objective-C. However, the javascript approach should work, and if you use something like phonegap you ought to be able to make it cross platform. There are lots of questions on stack overflow about doing this; I'll try to dig up a couple of references shortly.